# Why does the lookup by index value result in a key error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MNumber':['M03400001','M00000021','M10450001','M00003420','M02635915','M51323275','M63061229','M63151022'],
    'GPA':[3.01, 4.00, 2.95, 2.90, 3.50, 3.33, 2.99, 3.98],
    'major':['IS','BANA','IS','IS','IS','BANA','IS', 'BANA'],
    'internship':['P&G', 'IBM', 'P&G', 'IBM', 'P&G', 'EY','EY', 'Great American'],
    'job_offers':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4,3],
    'graduate_credits':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3,4]
})
x  =  df.groupby('internship').describe()
#print(x.info())
print(x["IBM"])
```

The error:

```
KeyError: 'IBM'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x['IBM']` tries to access the *column* `'IBM'`, which does not exist.
`x.loc['IBM']` accesses the row `'IBM'`, which does exist.

Comment: What's the difference between x.loc["IBM"] and x.loc["IBM",  :  ]   ?

Comment: @nicomp they're equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe `x` does not contain a key called `IBM`.

Try

```
print(x)
```

To see the keys contained in your dataframe.
Even better, you can try

```
print(x.columns)
```

To see the available columns of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas DataFrame groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) when used, it changes the `column` specified to `index` of the `DataFrame`. So, you should try to index the `row` rather than the `column` as stated by @timgeb.